# most effective method to manage employee performance reviews for a company's HR department

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Currently, our company uses a performance review document created with Adobe forms, which is distributed to employees for completion. Once completed, the document is returned to HR for review. HR then sends the document to the relevant manager for additional comments, before arranging a meeting with the employee to review and sign off the document. Once signed, the document is returned to HR for final approval from the director and digital filing. The question at hand is how to optimize this process for maximum efficiency using Microsoft flow.

Comment: Do you have a preliminary flow?
Can more information be provided?
Are your documents stored in SharePoint?